# Google Cloud Platform and MSSQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have an MSSQL 2008 r2 Express database and was wondering if it would be compatible on Google Cloud Platform's Windows Server 2016?

Totally new to databases and servers, so my apologies if not asking in the correct place.

Also, where would be the best place for advice on restoring a database from a backup?  Our external host got hacked and all our files are now encrypted.  I have a .bak backup of the database but the remote server's version of MSSQL 2008 seems to be newer than the version on my computer.  I get an error when trying to restore to a new blank database:

> The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.1600. 
>   That server is incompatible with this server which is running version
>   10.00.5538

I assume I would only be able to transfer whole databases and not just the backup of one.

All advice and pointers most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

> The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.1600. That server > is incompatible with this server which is running version 10.00.5538

The backup was made with SQL-Server 2008 R2 (Version 10.50....)
The SQL-Server where you trying to Restore is SQL-Server 2008 (Version 10.00....)

You must restore your backup on a SQL-Server 2008 R2  at least

Comment: Thanks for that Ebis.  I wish I still had access to server's 10.50 version but thanks to ransomware it has been encrypted.  I tried using the version on my computer but will look to see if there is a way to upgrade or install another version of the 2008 r2 Express software.